# Tables pagination issue in static website

Tags: javascript, php, css, html

I've a table that includes many YouTube videos like shown in [this pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ARkGU.png) and I don't want all these videos to show at the same time. What can I do? I tried `datatables.net` and `tablesorter.com`

```html
<table id="table_id" style="width: 100%;">
    <tr class="loading">
        <td class='td'>
         <div  class="layout" style="position: absolute;  z-index: 1; width: 485px; height: 280px; " onclick="this.style.display='none';"><strong>The Internet connection has</strong></div>
           <iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/w9DTUjrPTd0?wmode=opaque" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen  width="100%" height="100%" ></iframe>
        </td>
        <td class='td'>
         <div  class="layout" style="position: absolute;  z-index: 1; width: 485px; height: 280px; " onclick="this.style.display='none';"><strong>Arsenal vs man city <br> 3-2 <br> 23/5/215 <br> أرسنال ضد مانشيستر سيتي</strong></div>
           <iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/aDBDowU_lqc?wmode=opaque" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </td>

    </tr>
    <tr class="loading">
        <td class='td'>

         <div  class="layout" style="position: absolute;  z-index: 1; width: 485px; height: 280px; " onclick="this.style.display='none';"><strong>Communications' second year</strong></div>
           <iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ToACE9BTSCA?wmode=opaque" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </td>
         <td class='td'>
          <div  class="layout" style="position: absolute;  z-index: 1; width: 485px; height: 280px; " onclick="this.style.display='none';"><strong>Hello World</strong></div>
           <iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ToACE9BTSCA?wmode=opaque" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </td>
       
       
       
    </tr>
        <tr class="loading">
        <td class='td'><div  class="layout" style="position: absolute;  z-index: 1; width: 485px; height: 280px; " onclick="this.style.display='none';"><strong>Hello World</strong></div>
           <iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ToACE9BTSCA?wmode=opaque" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </td>
         <td class='td'><div  class="layout" style="position: absolute;  z-index: 1; width: 485px; height: 280px; " onclick="this.style.display='none';"><strong>Hello World</strong></div>
           <iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ToACE9BTSCA?wmode=opaque" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </td>
       
       
       
    </tr>
        <tr class="loading">
        <td class='td'><div  class="layout" style="position: absolute;  z-index: 1; width: 485px; height: 280px; " onclick="this.style.display='none';"><strong>Hello World</strong></div>
           <iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ToACE9BTSCA?wmode=opaque" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </td>
         <td class='td'><div  class="layout" style="position: absolute;  z-index: 1; width: 485px; height: 280px; " onclick="this.style.display='none';"><strong>Hello World</strong></div>
           <iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ToACE9BTSCA?wmode=opaque" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </td>
       
       
       
    </tr>
        <tr class="loading">
        <td class='td'><div  class="layout" style="position: absolute;  z-index: 1; width: 485px; height: 280px; " onclick="this.style.display='none';"><strong>Hello World</strong></div>
           <iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ToACE9BTSCA?wmode=opaque" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </td>
         <td class='td'><div  class="layout" style="position: absolute;  z-index: 1; width: 485px; height: 280px; " onclick="this.style.display='none';"><strong>Hello World</strong></div>
           <iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ToACE9BTSCA?wmode=opaque" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </td>
       
       
       
    </tr>
     <tr class="loading">
        <td class='td'>
         <div  class="layout" style="position: absolute;  z-index: 1; width: 485px; height: 280px; " onclick="this.style.display='none';"><strong>The Internet connection has</strong></div>
           <iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/w9DTUjrPTd0?wmode=opaque" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen  width="100%" height="100%" ></iframe>
        </td>
        <td class='td'>
         <div  class="layout" style="position: absolute;  z-index: 1; width: 485px; height: 280px; " onclick="this.style.display='none';"><strong>Arsenal vs man city <br> 3-2 <br> 23/5/215 <br> أرسنال ضد مانشيستر سيتي</strong></div>
           <iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/aDBDowU_lqc?wmode=opaque" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </td>

    </tr>
     <tr class="loading">
        <td class='td'>
         <div  class="layout" style="position: absolute;  z-index: 1; width: 485px; height: 280px; " onclick="this.style.display='none';"><strong>The Internet connection has</strong></div>
           <iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/w9DTUjrPTd0?wmode=opaque" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen  width="100%" height="100%" ></iframe>
        </td>
        <td class='td'>
         <div  class="layout" style="position: absolute;  z-index: 1; width: 485px; height: 280px; " onclick="this.style.display='none';"><strong>Arsenal vs man city <br> 3-2 <br> 23/5/215 <br> أرسنال ضد مانشيستر سيتي</strong></div>
           <iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/aDBDowU_lqc?wmode=opaque" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </td>

    </tr>
     <tr class="loading">
        <td class='td'>
         <div  class="layout" style="position: absolute;  z-index: 1; width: 485px; height: 280px; " onclick="this.style.display='none';"><strong>The Internet connection has</strong></div>
           <iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/w9DTUjrPTd0?wmode=opaque" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen  width="100%" height="100%" ></iframe>
        </td>
        <td class='td'>
         <div  class="layout" style="position: absolute;  z-index: 1; width: 485px; height: 280px; " onclick="this.style.display='none';"><strong>Arsenal vs man city <br> 3-2 <br> 23/5/215 <br> أرسنال ضد مانشيستر سيتي</strong></div>
           <iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/aDBDowU_lqc?wmode=opaque" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </td>

    </tr>
     <tr class="loading">
        <td class='td'>
         <div  class="layout" style="position: absolute;  z-index: 1; width: 485px; height: 280px; " onclick="this.style.display='none';"><strong>The Internet connection has</strong></div>
           <iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/w9DTUjrPTd0?wmode=opaque" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen  width="100%" height="100%" ></iframe>
        </td>
        <td class='td'>
         <div  class="layout" style="position: absolute;  z-index: 1; width: 485px; height: 280px; " onclick="this.style.display='none';"><strong>Arsenal vs man city <br> 3-2 <br> 23/5/215 <br> أرسنال ضد مانشيستر سيتي</strong></div>
           <iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/aDBDowU_lqc?wmode=opaque" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </td>

    </tr>
     <tr class="loading">
        <td class='td'>
         <div  class="layout" style="position: absolute;  z-index: 1; width: 485px; height: 280px; " onclick="this.style.display='none';"><strong>The Internet connection has</strong></div>
           <iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/w9DTUjrPTd0?wmode=opaque" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen  width="100%" height="100%" ></iframe>
        </td>
        <td class='td'>
         <div  class="layout" style="position: absolute;  z-index: 1; width: 485px; height: 280px; " onclick="this.style.display='none';"><strong>Arsenal vs man city <br> 3-2 <br> 23/5/215 <br> أرسنال ضد مانشيستر سيتي</strong></div>
           <iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/aDBDowU_lqc?wmode=opaque" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </td>

    </tr>
     <tr class="loading">
        <td class='td'>
         <div  class="layout" style="position: absolute;  z-index: 1; width: 485px; height: 280px; " onclick="this.style.display='none';"><strong>The Internet connection has</strong></div>
           <iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/w9DTUjrPTd0?wmode=opaque" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen  width="100%" height="100%" ></iframe>
        </td>
        <td class='td'>
         <div  class="layout" style="position: absolute;  z-index: 1; width: 485px; height: 280px; " onclick="this.style.display='none';"><strong>Arsenal vs man city <br> 3-2 <br> 23/5/215 <br> أرسنال ضد مانشيستر سيتي</strong></div>
           <iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/aDBDowU_lqc?wmode=opaque" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </td>

    </tr>
     <tr class="loading">
        <td class='td'>
         <div  class="layout" style="position: absolute;  z-index: 1; width: 485px; height: 280px; " onclick="this.style.display='none';"><strong>The Internet connection has</strong></div>
           <iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/w9DTUjrPTd0?wmode=opaque" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen  width="100%" height="100%" ></iframe>
        </td>
        <td class='td'>
         <div  class="layout" style="position: absolute;  z-index: 1; width: 485px; height: 280px; " onclick="this.style.display='none';"><strong>Arsenal vs man city <br> 3-2 <br> 23/5/215 <br> أرسنال ضد مانشيستر سيتي</strong></div>
           <iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/aDBDowU_lqc?wmode=opaque" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </td>

    </tr>

 
</table>
```

Comment: http://demo.tutorialzine.com/2010/05/sweet-pages-jquery-pagination-solution/demo.html

Comment: http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/infinite-page-scroll/

Comment: Is the problem that too much video's are loaded on pageload or that there are to many to display?

Comment: There are tutorials available on internet. please check them once

Comment: did you face any issue in using data table plugin of jQuery?

Comment: nothing happens except that when i reach the bottom of the page an alert appears  and told me that i reached the bottom!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Data tables should work perfectly for what you're trying to do.  Depending on the number of rows you have older versions of IE may get overwhelmed because of all the data you are putting in the dom, but this is not Data Tables specific, more a symptom of your static website instead of using a data driven site.

You didn't specify why the two options you mentioned didn't work, perhaps that would be a better question for this forum.  However if you're willing to entertain DataTables again, simply do the following steps:

1. Include jQuery
2. Include DataTables
3. Properly code your tables - this means using thead and tbody tags in addition to what you have, datatables will not work without this.

   ...
         
       
       
         
           ...
4. DataTable'ify your table by putting the following in a document ready in your javascript:

   $('#table_id').DataTable();
5. Profit!

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/8knrmdat/1/)

```
code here because so is being fickle
```

Comment: nothing happens except that when i reach the bottom of the page an alert appears  and told me that i reached the bottom!!!!

Comment: did you try the fiddle? its using your tables (modified as per my instructions above) and is working